# Existence of an isomorphism $\Bbb{Z}_{n}^{\times} \rightarrow \Bbb{Z}_{\phi(n)}^{+}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, group-isomorphism

I am considering the multiplicative group of units modulo $n$ which I shall refer to as $\Bbb{Z}_{n}^{\times}$. I read somewhere that

$$\Bbb{Z}_{n}^{\times} \cong \Bbb{Z}_{\phi(n)}^{+}$$

where $\phi(n)$ is the totient of $n$. I would like to know an explicit $$\pi_n: \Bbb{Z}_{n}^{\times} \rightarrow \Bbb{Z}_{\phi(n)}^{+}$$

That gives this isomorphism (as I would like to efficiently compute with it).

### Work To Find it Myself:

Classically $\pi_n(1) = 0$. (Trivial identity properties). Now one idea is that if I can find a single generator $\mu$ of $\Bbb{Z}_n^{\times}$, then I could set $\pi_n(\mu) = 1$ and from there generate the isomorphism, but it's not clear how to quickly find this generator in $\Bbb{Z}_n^{\times}$ without just trying out elements and seeing which one does enumerate through the whole set.

### Alternative Approach:

Intuitively it seems I am looking for a "modular logarithm" of some kind since we have that

$$ \pi_n(ab) = \pi_n(a) + \pi_n(b)$$

But logarithm w.r.t what base? That remains unclear to me. Perhaps it is a logarithm with base equal to a generator of $\Bbb{Z}_n^{\times}$. That seems natural so the problem still reduces to finding a single generator, and now, computing these logarithms.

### Motivation:

My friend was considering how to efficiently compute the period of $a^r \mod n$. I figured that if this isomorphism can be found I can use it to change the sequence $a,a^2 ... $ to $\pi_n(a), 2*pi_n(a) ... $ with the latter being very easy to analyze for length (since I can just consider the factors of $\pi_n(a)$ that divide $\phi(n)$

Comment: This is not an easy problem in general - the modular logarithm is the basis (so to speak) of Diffie-Hellman key exchange.

Comment: What if you already knew the prime factorization of $n$ would that make this any easier?

Comment: Yes, you have to know it, because $\mathbb Z_{n}^\times$ is only cyclic if $n$ is a prime, power of an odd prime, twice the power of an odd prime, or four.

Comment: ... which also shows that there won't be such an isomorphism in general because $\mathbb Z_k^+$ is always cyclic.

Comment: Where did you read that $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}/\varphi(n)\mathbb{Z}$?  This is not true in general: $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, for instance.  What is true is that $\#(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times = \varphi(n)$.

Comment: I think the elementary-number-theory tag may be technically correct, but is also misleading.